# Name Space for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

which namespace I can use for NavigationService.Navigate() in silverlight?

Comment: Please mark as answered,based on which you find is the correct answer.This may help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be in the code-behind of a `Page` class to refer to NavigationService:

[Page class documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Else, you can access the `Navigate()` method on a `Frame`.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591053(v=VS.95).aspx the namespace is `System.Windows.Navigation`.

If that's what you were looking for, the answer is trivial to find by looking in MSDN or any search engine.

Answer (score 0):

[Silverlight 3 Navigation API](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-3-Navigation-API.aspx)

- System.Windows.Controls
- System.Windows.Controls.Navigation

[Extract](http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Redirect-to-Another-Page-Within-Silverlight.aspx)....

```
xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
```

- and then had to add a frame (that i called "MainFrame") within the grid:
- and then finally was able to get to it via the buttonclick code this way (the page i was trying to navigate to is called "DashBoard"):

  Me.MainFrame.Navigate(New Uri("/Views/Dashboard.xaml", UriKind.Relative))

If you want the controls to go away within the frame, set the visibility to collapsed:

```
Label1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
Label2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
tbUserName.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
pbPassword.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
btnLogin.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed</navigation:frame>
```